# BottomNavigationView like instagram

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I'm developing an app which contains a BottomNavigationView (BNV).
Supposing that in that BNV we are going to insert 4 fragments: A, B, C, and D.
And in the fragment B, we can click on a button and show the fragment E.
My problem is, when I went to B and click to show E... I go to the fragment A and go back to the fragment B, I would like to show the latest fragment replaced there which is the fragment E. It's just like the BNV in instagram.

Any one have the solution please ?

Comment: can you post some of your code snippet? are you using Navigation Component?

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behaviour of BottomNavigationView for android.

https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#behavior

But luckily this behaviour has been modified in last version of navigation. Just add this in your gradle and you will have independents navigations:

```
// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-alpha10"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-alpha10"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-alpha10"
```

You can see the improve here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773#comment136